# A keyword for an "interesting point" in an image?

Tags: image-processing, neural-network

Actually I am searching for today's state of the art neural network model for detecting "an interesting point" in an image but I lacks the proper keyword for it.

For example, if an image is a portrait that point might be person's face. If it is an image of one flower in a vest, that point would be the flower's petals. It is the point that would catch the viewer's eye first. I want to know are there any convolutional neural network model that takes an input image and return a point like this?

For detecting one answer from an image it would be "classification", for detecting pixels area it would be "semantic segmentation". But for one coordinate from an image, I am not sure.

I thought by now someone would have already invented or even trained a network for tasks like this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called Saliency Detection.
[Ubernet](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.02132.pdf) supports saliency (among other features).